# SUM result value repeats even with case statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, sum

I'm using posgresql as a database and java as programming language with hibernate. My problem is this query:

```
select cast(sum(CASE WHEN p.nropack > 0 THEN p.nropack ELSE 0 END) as integer),
cast(sum(CASE WHEN p.nropack < 0 THEN p.nropack ELSE 0 END) as integer),
cast(p.fechareg as date) 
from pronostico p 
inner join aeropuerto a on (a.idaeropuerto=p.idaeropuerto)
inner join ciudad c on (a.idciudad=c.idciudad)
inner join pais ps on (ps.idpais=c.idpais)
inner join continente ct on (ct.idcontinente=ps.idcontinente)
where c.idciudad=105
group by cast (p.fechareg as date);
```

As a result I get:

```
sum;sum;fechareg 
30;-15;"2012-11-15"
```

But when I use it in my program:

```
public ArrayList<RepKardex> listarKardex(int ciud){  
    ciud=105; 
    ArrayList<RepKardex> listaKardex = new ArrayList<>();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();        
    String q = "select cast(sum( case when p.nropack > 0 then p.nropack ELSE 0 end ) as integer), "
            + "cast(sum( case when p.nropack < 0 then p.nropack ELSE 0 end ) as integer), "
            + "cast(p.fechareg as date) "
            + "from Pronostico p "
            + "inner join Aeropuerto a on (p.idaeropuerto = a.idaeropuerto) "
            + "inner join Ciudad c on (a.idciudad = c.idciudad) "
            + "inner join Pais ps on (c.idpais = ps.idpais) "
            + "inner join Continente ct on (ct.idcontinente = ps.idcontinente) "
            + "where c.idciudad = :ciud "
            + "group by cast(p.fechareg as date) ";                    
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(q);        
    query.setInteger("ciud", ciud);
    List lista = query.list();        
    Iterator iter = lista.iterator(); 
    while (iter.hasNext()) {    
        Object[] row = (Object[]) iter.next();            
        if (row!=null){
            System.out.println("entrantes : "+(Integer)row[0]); 
            System.out.println("salientes : "+(Integer)row[1]); 
            RepKardex rep = new RepKardex((int)row[0],(int)row[1],(Date)row[2]);              
            listaKardex.add(rep);
        }

    }

    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return listaKardex;
}
```

It prints

```
entrantes: 30
salida:    30
```

Can someone help me figure out why it repeats the positive numbers even when I use the case statement inside the query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not familiar with java, but if the query returns the values you are expecting maybe the problem is in the way you process the returned value, can you try and print the content of row as a whole and not row[0] or row[1] and see what comes out?

Comment: I've seen some systems get confused when there is more than one column with the same name (sum), but I have no idea if that is what's causing your problem. Can you try and see what happens when you explicitly name your columns? `select cast(sum(CASE WHEN p.nropack > 0 THEN p.nropack ELSE 0 END) as integer) as sum1, ... as sum2, ...`

Comment: @hvd Thanks!, this solve the problem. I don't certainly know why this happens but I think is because without the explicit name for the columns It considers the both sum functions as one, maybe?. Well thank you again and the other who help me too.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query with [`LEAST` and `GREATEST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```
SELECT sum(GREATEST(p.nropack, 0))::int AS entrantes
      ,sum(LEAST(p.nropack, 0))::int AS salida
      ,p.fechareg::date AS fechareg
from   pronostico  p 
JOIN   aeropuerto  a ON a.idaeropuerto = p.idaeropuerto
JOIN   ciudad      c ON c.idciudad = a.idciudad
JOIN   pais       ps ON ps.idpais = c.idpais
JOIN   continente ct ON ct.idcontinente = ps.idcontinente
where  c.idciudad = 105
GROUP  BY p.fechareg::date;
```

Other than that it looks just fine. I see no way the second column could return a positive number. Something else must go wrong here.

#### Edit:

[Comment by @hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409514/sum-result-value-repeats-even-with-case-statement/13413539#comment18329010_13409514) helped to find that the client code seems to get confused by identical column names (both sum columns defaulted to `"sum"`). Explicit column aliases seem to fix this.

Comment: Thanks. This simplifies the query although the cast doesn´t work when I put it in the program because hibernate use the character ':' to invoke parameters in the query. I use the greatest and least though